# Enclosed floor plan where one room has an odd number of doors

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to create an enclosed floor plan where only one room has an odd number of doors?

If you create a door to the outside then the outside also becomes a room. So your enclosed space would then include the outside.

Comment: No, if you sum the number of doors in each room you get twice the number of doors. This sum is even, so it has an even number of odd summands.

Comment: How do you get from that statement to "Therefore there cannot be only one room that has an odd number of doors"?

Comment: the number of rooms with an odd number of doors in even, and one is not even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine putting a letter on both sides of each door. The total number of letters will be even.

The number of doors in each room is the same as the number of letters visible in that room. So that is also an even sum. So there must be an even number of rooms (including possibly zero) that have an odd number of doors, in order to make that sum even.

In particular there cannot only be exactly one room with an odd number of doors.

---

This holds as long as every door is a two-way connection between rooms. If you define other kinds of doors, other spaces that are not rooms, etc, then of course it can be broken.

Comment: ...and now I want to write a story that involves a revolving door at the corner where three rooms meet... :-)